# Is there a way to write a function to manipulate the vim runtimepath variable?

Tags: vim

I have these lines in my vimrc:

```
let basepath=','.'~/.vim/plugged/'

" theme plugins
let &runtimepath.=basepath . 'morhetz/gruvbox'
let &runtimepath.=basepath . 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
let &runtimepath.=basepath . 'edkolev/tmuxline.vim'
```

Is there a way to write a function that encapsulates this behaviour? I wanted to right something like this:

```
loadplugin('somebody/plugin.vim')
```

And that would have the same effect as this line:

```
let &runtimepath.=basepath . 'somebody/plugin.vim'
```

Comment: Are you aware that plugins like [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) already do things like that?

Comment: @IngoKarkat, not only that but the OP mentioning `plugged` seems to imply he/she is already using one.

Comment: @romainl, I'm trying to exactly not having to use one, to simplify my setup because I git clone all the dependencies myself, and I think I've succeded. That little function below seals the deal: https://github.com/ninrod/dotfiles/tree/master/vim

Comment: You don't have to use a plugin manager. Pathogen is an install and forget masterpiece.

Comment: @romainl, I agree. pathogen is awesome. But I'm really into simplifying my config as much as I can. I strive to have just really the bare bones minimum. That means I don't have to fear updating pathogen 5 years from now even if it is indeed a masterpiece. That little function is convenient enough for me. I mean, it can't get any simples than [this](https://github.com/ninrod/dotfiles/blob/999ad8766228bf5cde3d6172d101f1a0a70a9d86/vim/functions.vim#L1-L5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, I found the answer:

```
function LoadPlugin(plugin)
  let basepath=','.'~/.vim/plugged/'
  let &runtimepath.=basepath . a:plugin
endfunction

"invoke this way
call LoadPlugin('somebody/plugin.vim')
```

Answer (score 1):

For the common case, i.e. when you don't care about non-existing paths, you could simply have executed

```
exe 'set rtp+='.basepath.a:plugin
```

For similar kinds of path handling, I've come up with [a function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/path.vim) that only adds the path if not already present, and only if it exists.

```
" autoload/lh/path.vim
" Function: lh#path#munge(pathlist, path) {{{3
function! lh#path#munge(pathlist, path) abort
  if type(a:pathlist) == type('str')
    let pathlist = split(a:pathlist, ',')
    return join(lh#path#munge(pathlist, a:path), ',')
  else
    if ! empty(glob(a:path))
      call lh#list#push_if_new(a:pathlist, a:path)
    endif
    return a:pathlist
  endif
endfunction

" autoload/lh/list.vim
" Function: lh#list#push_if_new(list, value) {{{3
function! lh#list#push_if_new(list, value) abort
  if index(a:list, a:value) < 0
    call add (a:list, a:value)
  endif
  return a:list
endfunction
```